# how to fix the 'Unknown provider: $compileProvider' error in angular-meteor app

Tags: meteor, angular-meteor

I'm building an angular-meteor app, where the main angular module is named "collector"

When I load the app, I see the following error in the browser console:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module collector due to:   loneleeandroo_ngmeteor.js:111
[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module angular-meteor due to:
[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module angular-meteor.template due to:
[$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $compileProvider
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.14/$injector/unpr?p0=%24compileProvider
minErr/<@http://localhost:3000/packages/loneleeandroo_ngmeteor.js?34ad21c0b396f189ccb67fbd89ea5ed4108d0168:111:5
createInjector/providerCache.$injector<@http://localhost:3000/packages/loneleeandroo_ngmeteor.js?34ad21c0b396f189ccb67fbd89ea5ed4108d0168:3631:13
getService@http://localhost:3000/packages/loneleeandroo_ngmeteor.js?34ad21c0b396f189ccb67fbd89ea5ed4108d0168:3758:11
loadModules/<@http://localhost:3000/packages/loneleeandroo_ngmeteor.js?34ad21c0b396f189ccb67fbd89ea5ed4108d0168:3712:17
forEach@http://localhost:3000/packages/loneleeandroo_ngmeteor.js?34ad21c0b396f189ccb67fbd89ea5ed4108d0168:355:7
loadModules@http://localhost:3000/pack
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: can you share some more details? how you configure angular modules in app.js? maybe this link will help https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/10914

Comment: This is what I currently have in my app.js:  angular.module('collector',['angular-meteor','ui.router',
    'angularFileUpload','ngDropdowns']);

Comment: do you have a way to reproduce it? a fork in github maybe?

Comment: here is another link with clues: https://github.com/Urigo/angular-meteor/issues/196

Comment: what is the angular meteor version in your versions file under .meteor?

Comment: urigo:angular                     0.8.14* The simplest no-conflict way to use AngularJS with Meteor